# Problem with Java Timer

Tags: java, timer, ubuntu-10.04

I am having a weird problem with timers...  My Timer works correctly when testing in NetBeans, but as soon as I compile and run directly from the terminal (Ubuntu 10.4), the task that is supposed to occur every minute executes once and never executes again...

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
{
    // schedule db update task to occur every 15 mins
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask ()
        {
            @Override public void run()
            {
                doUpdate();
            }
        } , 0, updateInterval * 1000 * 60 );
        System.out.print("Starting auto update @ ");

    // schedule cpu usage check to occur every 1 min
    Timer cpu = new Timer();
    cpu.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask ()
        {
            @Override public void run()
            {
                getCPU();
            }
        } , 0, cpuUpdateInterval * 1000 * 60 );
}
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: hmm did you debug, and check the values of cpuUpdateInterval? could they  have different values? this sounds like it could be platform (VM) dependent...

Comment: cpuUpdateInterval = 1.  im running it in netbeans in ubuntu(no problems), then compiling and running from the jar (only runs the doUpdate() timer).  I even made it just do a println everytime it enters the second timer.  It is never called after the first execution.

Comment: I would check the Java version on the command line and from Netbeans--you may be able to debug by switching which JVM Netbeans is using to run your app.

Comment: that was the problem.  Netbeans was 1.6.0, but the version returned by java -version from terminal was 1.5.0.  I updated and all is well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code,

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503829 */
public class TimerTest {

    private static final int MAX = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Timer cpu = new Timer();
        cpu.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            private int count;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Count: " + count);
                if (count == MAX) {
                    cpu.cancel();
                }
            }
        }, 100, 1000);
    }
}
```

I got the expected results:

```
$ make run
java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.2) (6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
java TimerTest
Count: 1
Count: 2
Count: 3
Count: 4
Count: 5
Count: 6
Count: 7
Count: 8
```

Answer (score 2):

What does `getCPU()` do?  If it is running JNA/JNI code or an external library, maybe you are missing the library from your command line settings.